# Adobe Flash Pro: Locate asset with missing font

Tags: flash, fonts

I transferred my work to a new computer, and when I open my .fla file, Adobe Flash is telling me that I'm missing a font. Is there any easy to locate which asset in my library is using that missing font? Because I'm pretty sure I no longer need the font, meaning I've got an old unused asset somewhere that is causing that error message to pop up. I would like to locate and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a backup of it and then started deleting assets to see if it would go away until I found the one that was doing it.